# Managing dependencies in a shared package

Tags: node.js, pnpm

I'm facing an issue with managing dependencies in a NestJS project where I have multiple APIs. My goal is to centralize all dependencies in a shared module (api-common) and then use this shared module in other APIs without having to install dependencies separately for each API.

Here's my project structure:

```
- api-common
  - package.json
  - tsconfig.json
  - node_modules
    - @nestjs
      - common
      - other_modules

- api-admin
  - package.json
  - tsconfig.json
  - node_modules
    - @client
      - api-common (linked using file:../api-common)

- api-freeman
  - package.json
  - tsconfig.json
  - node_modules
    - @client
      - api-common (linked using file:../api-common)
```

In both api-admin and api-freeman, I've linked api-common using `"@client/api-common": "file:../api-common"` in `package.json`. The api-common project contains various dependencies, including `@nestjs/common`.

However, when I try to import modules from `@nestjs/common` in my api-admin or api-other projects, I'm getting errors like `"Cannot find module '@nestjs/common' or its corresponding type declarations".`

I've already verified that `@nestjs/common` is installed in the node_modules of api-common.

I'm using `pnpm` as my package manager.

Comment: To achieve that you'll have to link all dependencies. api-admin will not start looking in other directories for nestjs unless you tell it to.

You should look at workspaces : https://pnpm.io/workspaces